# How to get the most commented articles using SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

We have 2 tables: `articles`, `comments`. 
The structure of this tables:

```
articles(article_id(PK), etc);

comments(comment_id(PK), article_id(FK)).
```

I need to get a list of the most commented articles.
I used the request:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, COUNT(comments.article_id) 
FROM comments
INNER JOIN articles ON comments.article_id = articles.article_id AND comments.article_id = :article_id.
```

What should be the request to get an array of data with 3 most commented articles? 
Is it really possible to do this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want with this query:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, COUNT(comments.article_id) AS num_comments
FROM comments
INNER JOIN articles ON comments.article_id = articles.article_id
GROUP BY articles.article_id
ORDER BY num_comments DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the article id, then a `join` is not necessary:

```
SELECT c.article_id, COUNT(*) AS num_comments
FROM comments c
GROUP BY c.article_id
ORDER BY num_comments DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will provide to you a list of articles and the number of comments for each of these articles ordering them in descending order of number_of_comments

```
SELECT articles.article_id, COUNT(comments.article_id) AS comment_count
FROM articles, comments
WHERE articles.article_id=comments.article_id
GROUP BY articles.article_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easier way, you can add *'n-comments'* column on the article table and initialize it to zero, and with your function to submit a comment, update the value of the 'n-comments++' after every comment.

thin every article will contain the number of its comments, and it will be very easy to select the most commented articles by:
*"SELECT article_id FROM articles ORDER BY n-comments DESC LIMIT 50"*

I think it will be easier and faster, hope it can help